# Using the Select statement to add conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use the select statement to select surname and dob of all female students in the class "A1". At the moment I have something like this:

select surname, date_of_birth, sex from class where P_id = A1;

How do I alter this select statement to limit it to female students? I am also trying to list the results by surname.

Comment: use `limit N` at the end of the statement

Comment: Depends on what the sex field contains. Usually M or F. Add to your WHERE clause. sex = 'F'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT surname, date_of_birth, sex FROM class WHERE sex = 'F' AND surname 
IN ('surname1', 'surname2', 'surname3') AND P_id = 'A1'
```

You will need to change `sex = 'F'` if you've stored `sex` differently in your tables. Also, your `surname` will probably be different.